# Singular solution to a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I would really appreciate any help with this problem. It might be trivial but I am confused by it nonetheless as I am new to the field of ODE. I was tasked  with solving this equation:
$$y'\tan(x)=a+y$$ where $a$ is real. I understand that this is an equation with separable variables so I divided it by $(a+y)\tan(x),y\not=-a,x\not=k\pi$ and obtained $$\frac{dy}{a+y}=\cot(x)dx$$ After integration of both sides I got general solution given by: $$y=c\sin(x)-a$$ where $c$ is arbitrary constant. It is easy to show these functions actually are solutions by just plugging them in initial equation. I am also aware that during division step some solutions might be lost so we should check if there are any. And sure enough, $y=-a$ is a solution because it makes both sides of equation equal to $0$. But why are $x=k\pi$ solutions as well? My textbook claims these functions are also singular solutions without verifying it. So my question is how to verify this claim as I am a bit confused how to calculate $y'$ in this instance? And what is even $y$? Maybe I should multiply whole equation with dx and calculate differentials or something else? Any help is welcome.

Comment: It is quiet strange, because when $y'\equiv \frac{dy}{dx}$ is used in problem formulation, it is forbidden for $dx$ which is in the denominator to be zero or, equivalently, for $x$ to be constant

Comment: Yes, it really is puzzling because this equation is not in the form something1*dx+something2*dy=0 where I think it is allowed to divide by either dx or dy and have an equation in y' or x'. Only thing which comes to mind is multiplying equation by dx so it becomes tan(x)dy=(a+y)dx. If we assume x is function of y, that is x=f(y), then dx=f'(y)dy where f' is derivative with respect to y. But then $k\pi$ doesn't contain y so f'(y)=0. This would make both sides equal to zero, and it would seem $x=k\pi$ is a solution, but is this new equation equivalent to old one? Is this even allowed to do?

Comment: $dx$ can't be $0$, it is the same as $x=2$ **is not** a root for $\frac{(x-2)^2}{x-2}=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an ODE is written in the form $y'=\cdots$ or $G(x,y,y')=0$ you usually restrict yourself to solutions which are **functions** $y=y(x)$. But you can look at the equation in a more "symmetric" way, the so called differential form
$$
\cot x dx-\frac{dy}{a+y}=0
$$
and seek solutions in implicit form $F(x,y)=0$, not necessarily functional relations $x\to y$. For example, you can look for solutions where $x=g(y)$. If you divide your differential form by $dy$ throughout you get a new differential equation which admits the constants $x=g(y)=k\pi$ as solutions.

In the past, differential equations were written in the more flexible differential form, but recently (last 100 or so years) mathematicians have favored the "functional" version, where your solutions have to be functions, a mania of some sort. For example, the differential equation
$$
xdx+ydy=0
$$
according to the modern standard would have solutions which are upper or lower half-circles. For XXVIII century mathematicians though, the whole circles were solutions.

Comment: I remember our professor saying that this differential form is interchangeable with an equation. To me it meant that whenever we get an equation to solve, it is actually two equations, one in y' and the other in x'. This would explain my initial question if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: @baja1997 Well.. this is essentially correct. It is sad though that due to the psychological need to avoid all "differential language" in Calculus, and replacing everything by finite relations this type of ugly presentations came into being.

Comment: Luckily, the language of differential forms restores the symmetry here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Those values are just things you need to check, not necessarily solutions.

The same phenomenon occurs in regular equations: when you divide by an expression involving the variable (or apply a non-reversible function to your expression), you need to check whether setting the expression equal to $0$ will lead to a solution... but it may not.

For example, in solving $7-x=\sqrt{2x+1}$, if you square both sides to get $49-14x+x^2 = 2x+1$ and then solve the resulting quadratic, $x^2-16x+48=0$, you get $x=4$ and $x=12$ as solutions... So you need to *check* if they are solutions; but only $x=4$ is a solution.

Here you have to exclude the case of $x=k\pi$ for the resulting equatin to make sense. Then you need to check whether those values must be omitted from the original equation... and they do not. In fact, the values $x=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$ are the ones excluded from the original equation (those are the ones where the equation is not defined).

So kudos for realizing the division means some checks need to be made at the end; just remember that those are *checks*: you do not know for sure they lead to solutions, just that they are things that you omitted from your calculations, so you need to check if they need to be allowed back in.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.